# Creating a check box dynamically

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Can we create a checkbox dynamically on a window in progress? Actually i have created combo-box,frame,fill-in dynamically but not getting the idea how can I Create checkbox dynamically.

Comment: Google site:documentation.progress.com create checkbox

Answer (score 1):

```
display "Example" skip(2) with frame a width 80.

define variable h as handle no-undo.
create toggle-box h assign
  row = 2
  column = 1
  label = "hi there"
  frame = frame a:handle
  sensitive = true
  visible = true
.

wait-for window-close of current-window.
```